# How to make a link live in a pdf with xfinium

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin

I am trying to build a pdf tool with xfinium library and I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the pdf links of a pdf to make them live when displayed in my app. For now I can only see them as text and it is not possible to click on them so they are not useful. I have looked in the samples of xfinium but I couldn't find any hint to what I should change to make them work.

Any help would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links in the PDF file are stored as link annotations. You can retrieve these links in this way: load your file in a PdfFixedDocument. The document's Pages collection is populated automatically with all the pages in the document. 
Each page has an Annotations collection which is populated automatically with all the annotations on the page. Loop through this collection and test which annotation is a link annotation. The position of the link on the page is given by the VisualRectangle property.
If you need the link's URL you have to inspect the Action property of the link annotation. If it is an URI action then URI property of the action will give you the link's URL.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops XFINIUM.PDF library.

Comment: What if the link targets another page/location within the same pdf?
In this case all actions are null.

Comment: @StefanFabian When the actions are null, probably the Destination property is set on the link annotation.

Comment: Destination is null as well.

Comment: @StefanFabian In this situation we have to see the file. Please post a link to download it or send it to our support.

Comment: Here you go: https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~ebfox/publication-files/PhDthesis_ebfox.pdf Any link in the table of contents or any citation link on page 23 should do.